# how to send "order is confirmed emails to customer" in django

Tags: reactjs, django, email, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an e-commerce website in Django and react. but I am not able to find a way for this scenario.
whenever a user purchases something a confirmation email should go to the user and one to the admin that a user buy something.
can we do this just by code or we have to use something like Mailchimp?i want to do it by writing code.

Comment: Sending emails can be done using django's send_email methods. The hosting company or the cloud provider needs to have an SMTP mail server or solution running that will actually "send" the emails.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a service like Mailchimp for this. You need to write your own code for sending emails.

To send emails in Django you need to configure a mail server. You can use your own mail server or use providers like AWS SES (Simple Email Service) or SendGrid.

Then you need to write the code that will send two emails after the purchase. Ideally, it should be done in the webhook that will wait for payment confirmation from your payment provider (for example Stripe).

BTW, I'm working on Django+React tutorials at [SaaSitive](https://saasitive.com) and just committed example code how to send activation emails (after registration) https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate